# Best way to implement a read and write for an unknown amount of rows

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I asked a question similarly, but the outcome was pretty messy and I was having difficulties populating so I'm trying to go at from a different angle: 
[Question concerning asp:listview and multiple dynamically created controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060835/question-concerning-asplistview-and-multiple-dynamically-created-controls)

I have a table which stores steps in a process. Some companies only have 6 steps while others have 15, so I created a table with 15 different slots for steps. What I would like to do is set up a control that displays each step in its own row with a label next to it saying "Step '#'", and not in an adjacent column. I'd also like for it to not display any blank rows. If they are entering the step instructions, I would want for them to have to press a button that would add a row so that they aren't just given 15 empty text boxes to fill in.

What would be the best control to do this in, and how would I get started in setting it up?

Comment: Your data model is flawed. You shouldn't be storing steps as columns in the first place. Correct that issue and this one will fall away naturally.

Comment: Should I make a table that stores 1 step and a foreign key to the customer name, and just populate all steps from this customer etc? Is that the better way of doing it?

Comment: Yeah, that takes care of guessing what the max number of steps would be, and makes displaying them a piece of cake.

Comment: I see, well will one of you move your comment to a response so I can mark as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting data in the field names in the table, which makes your task more complicated. Instead of storing the steps in columns, like this:

```
CompanyId  Step1  Step2  Step3  Step4  Step5  Step 6  Step7 ...
1          alpha  beta   gamma
2          one    two    three  four   five
```

You should store the steps as rows, so that you get the step number as data in a field:

```
CompanyId  StepNumber  Step
1          1           alpha
1          2           beta
1          3           gamma
2          1           one
2          2           two
2          3           three
2          4           four
2          5           five
```

This way you don't get any unused fields, and the data model doesn't pose any limitation on the number of steps. Also, you can easily get the steps as a collection instead of having to get each one separately and add to a collection.

Something like:

```
var steps =
  from s in CompanySteps
  where s.CompanyId = 2
  orderby s.StepNumber
  select new { s.StepNumber, s.Step };
```

Then you have many different options to display the steps, like using the collection as data source in a Repeater, or loop through the items and just create HTML code for them and put in a Literal control.